# Не записывается указатель на структуру

Tags: c++, c

Столкнулся с проблемой, но в интернете подходящего мне решения не нашел. 
Пишу программу на C нахождения точек пересечения отрезка и треугольника. Функция должна возвращать одну точку, две или NULL, который говорит о том, что пересечений нет. Первое, что мне пришло в голову, это возвращать указатель на указатель как если бы вместо структурного типа переменной был простой.

```
Point ** getIntersectionOfTrnLine(const Triangle tr, const Line line)
{
    Point ** ptr = (Point **)malloc(2 * sizeof(Point *));
    if (!ptr) return NULL;

    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    ptr[0] = getIntersectionOfTwoIntercepts(&(Line) { tr.dot1, tr.dot2 }, &line); // возвращает указатель на точку пересечения двух отрезков или NULL
    ptr[1] = getIntersectionOfTwoIntercepts(&(Line) { tr.dot2, tr.dot3 }, &line);
    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    if (!ptr[0] && !ptr[1]) {

        ptr[0] = getIntersectionOfTwoIntercepts(&(Line) { tr.dot1, tr.dot3 }, &line);

        if (!ptr[0]) {

            free(ptr[0]);
            free(ptr[1]);
            free(ptr);
            return NULL;
        }
        else {

            ptr = (Point **)realloc(sizeof(Point *));
            return ptr;
        }
    }

    if (!ptr[1]) {

        ptr[1] = getIntersectionOfTwoIntercepts(&(Line) { tr.dot1, tr.dot3 }, &line);

        if (!ptr[1]) {

            ptr = (Point **)realloc(sizeof(Point *));
            return ptr;
        }

        if (ptr[0]->x == ptr[1]->x && ptr[0]->y == ptr[1]->y) {

            ptr = (Point **)realloc(sizeof(Point *));
            return ptr;
        }

        return ptr;
    }

    if (!ptr[0]) {

        ptr[0] = getIntersectionOfTwoIntercepts(&(Line) { tr.dot1, tr.dot3 }, &line);

        if (!ptr[0]) {

            ptr[0]->x = ptr[1]->x;
            ptr[0]->y = ptr[1]->y;

            ptr = (Point **)realloc(sizeof(Point *));
            return ptr;
        }

        if (ptr[0]->x == ptr[1]->x && ptr[0]->y == ptr[1]->y) {

            ptr[0]->x = ptr[1]->x;
            ptr[0]->y = ptr[1]->y;

            ptr = (Point **)realloc(sizeof(Point *));
            return ptr;
        }

        return ptr;
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Функция, которая между восклицательными знаками, возвращает указатель на точку пересечения и первый записывается в ptr[0], а вот второй указатель никуда не записывается. В отладчике можно увидеть, что функция вернула указатель, однако он не записался. [image: Картинка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш указатель ptr это просто указатель и "официально" он не хранит своего размера. Поэтому отладчик не знает сколько элементов отображать и отображает только один (и он прав). Хотите видеть второе значение? спросите об этом у отладчика явно - в списке контрольных значений добавьте `ptr[1]`.

В любом случае, я даже не знаю, как этот код собрался - realloc  с одним параметром официально не существует, перегрузки в си нет (есть, через макросы, но вряд ли Вы это используете), значит просто неправильно используете функцию.

Во вторых, сравнивать вещественные числа на равенство нужно очень аккуратно, обычно сравнивают через модуль разности меньше некого маленького значения.

Также похоже, что в коде есть утечки памяти. Но на все эти вопросы сложно ответить - не видно всего кода, а некоторые конструкции у меня вызывают большие вопросы.

Comment: А как мне сказать, чтобы отображалось 2 элемента?

Comment: То есть как сделать, чтобы отладчик отображал два элемента?